# Triangle issue in Java

Tags: java

I want to write a code to draw left triangle. I added the pseudo code of what I did so far :

```
 for(int i =1 ; i <= 10 ; i++ )  // main loop
{
   if(i<=5)
   {
       for(int h= 1 ; h <= 5 ; h++ )  //sub loop
           if(h<=i)      // my conditions in 1st case
               System.out.print(h);
   }
   else
        for(int h= 1 ; h <= 4 ; h++ ) // 2nd sub loop
            if(h<=i) // 2nd conditions and reason for error 
                System.out.print(h);

   System.out.println();
```

This code gives me the following output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

My expected output is:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

I can not find where did I mistake. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: In the second loop, `h` will always be less than `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've meant this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (i <= 5) {
        for (int h = 1; h <= 5; h++) {
            if (h <= i) {
                System.out.print(h);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int h = 1; h <= 10 - i; h++) {
            if (h <= i) {
                System.out.print(h);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The difference is the condition of the second loop - `10 - i` instead of `h <= 4`. On a side note, I suggest you work on your indentation, and always use braces after loops and `if`s. Readability is important.

A slightly simpler, and more readable version of the same code would be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int h = 1; h <= i; h++) {
        System.out.print(h);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for (int i = 6; i < 11; i++) {
    for (int h = 1; h <= 10 - i; h++) {
        System.out.print(h);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here, I've used two loops and no `if` statements, so there's less nesting.

Comment: The second version is much better IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your condition on your second inner for loop to

```
for (int h = 1; h <= 10 - i; h++)
```

You end result would be something like this:

```
    for(int i =1 ; i <= 10 ; i++ ){
        if(i<=5){
            for(int h= 1 ; h <= 5 ; h++ )  //sub loop
                if(h<=i)
                    System.out.print(h);
        }else{
            for(int h= 1 ; h <= 10 - i ; h++ ) // 2nd sub loop
                if(h<=i) // 2nd conditions and reason for error 
                    System.out.print(h);
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) //i <= 9 to remove 0
{
    if(i <= 5)
    {
        for(int h = 1; h <= i; h++)
        {
            System.out.print(h);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int h = 1; h < (10-i); h++) //mirrors numbers around 5 (7-->3...)
        {
            System.out.print(h);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This makes then numbers greater than 5 decrease by the amount they are greater than 5 i.e. 6 is 5 + 1 thus yielding 4. Or in other words mirrors them around the 5 pole when they are greater than 5.

Also when you make your first for loop go up to 10 there will be an additional 0 at the end, just make the first for loop go up to 9.